# How to setup Oracle using SSL and JDBC

Tags: oracle, ssl, jdbc, https, certificate

I am struck configuring Oracle SSL. Could someone tell me the detailed steps to update the configuration and how to use in JDBC?

Refer to https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12517_01/back_office/pdf/141/html/pos_sg/appendix_jdbc_oracle.htm#CHDBAFEC

What I have done is

1. generate the wallet and export the keystore

```
orapki wallet create -wallet E:\app\wallet -pwd core@123 -auto_login

orapki wallet add -wallet E:\app\wallet -pwd core@123 -dn "CN=localhost, OU=Example Department, O=Example Company, L=Birmingham, ST=West Midlands, C=GB" -keysize 1024 -self_signed -validity 365

orapki wallet pkcs12_to_jks -wallet E:\app\wallet -pwd core@123 -jksKeyStoreLoc E:\app\wallet\oracle_ks.jks -jksKeyStorepwd core@123 -jksTrustStoreLoc E:\app\wallet\oracle_ts.jks -jksTrustStorepwd core@123
```

2. Update the oracle_home/network/admin
   2.1 listener.ora

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = CBX-PF217JHT-E490)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = CBX-PF217JHT-E490)(PORT = 2484))
    )
  )  
  

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = E:\app\virtual

SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE
WALLET_LOCATION =
  (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA =
      (DIRECTORY = E:\app\wallet)
    )
  )
```

2.2 sqlnet.ora

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (BEQ, TCPS)
SSL_VERSION = 3.0
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE
WALLET_LOCATION =
  (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA =
      (DIRECTORY = E:\app\wallet)
    )
  )
DIAG_ADR_ENABLED = OFF
```

2.3 tnsnames.ora

```
LISTENER_ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = CBX-PF217JHT-E490)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = CBX-PF217JHT-E490)(PORT = 2484))
    )
  )
  
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = CBX-PF217JHT-E490)(PORT = 1521))
      (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = CBX-PF217JHT-E490)(PORT = 2484))
      (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = orcl))
    )
  )
```

3. Update DataSource url to be

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL=tcps) (HOST=localhost) (PORT=2484) ) (CONNECT_DATA= (SERVICE_NAME=orcl))
```

4. Whith startup of Tomcat add such parameter

```
-Doracle.net.ssl_cipher_suites=TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="E:\app\wallet\oracle_ts.jks" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="core@123" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType="JKS" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="E:\app\wallet\oracle_ks.jks" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType="JKS" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword="core@123"
```

But I still cannot start up with Tomcat. Could someone tell me which step is wrong or what else configuration I should do?

Here is the error log when start up tomcat

```
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: NL Exception was generated TNS-04610: No literals left, reached end of NV pair
        at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAddrTree(AddrResolution.java:777)
        at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:510)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:660)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:286)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1438)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:518)
        ... 43 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing parenthesis at the end of your URL:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=localhost) (PORT=2484))(CONNECT_DATA= (SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify the JDBC version and JDK version that you are using? Did you check the [blog for 12.2 and lower](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/ssl-connection-to-oracle-db-using-jdbc%2C-tlsv12%2C-jks-or-oracle-wallets)? Also, after 18c, you can add all properties into ojdbc.properties file and use it as described in the [quickstart guide to ATP.](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/java-connectivity-to-atp.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and got the following exception while creating connection from SQL Developer:
NL Exception was generated TNS-04610: No literals left, reached end of NV pair

The problem was with the wrong connection string - one closing bracket was missing:
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL=tcps) (HOST=localhost) (PORT=2484) ) (CONNECT_DATA= (SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))